# Trouble horizontally centering <div> containing <ul>

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list

I can't seem to get my list to center. The li elements center just fine but it seems that I can't get my ul to center on the page.

I need the ul or the ul's container to be width: 100%; for I want to have a background for the ul which should stretch to fill the page width and the ul+margin height.

I have looked around the webb but no answers seem to fit my needs, this is my first question and I'm new to this scene so please be understanding if I've done anything wrong.

HTML (with php to be used in Wordpress)

```
<div class="body-news">
    <ul id="newsbar">   
            <li>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'in-body-widget-area' ); ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'in-body-widget-area2' ); ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'in-body-widget-area3' ); ?>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.body-news{
}
    .body-news ul{
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
        #newsbar li{
            text-align: left;
            float: left;
            display:inline;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 15px 20px;
        }
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle to demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Will try, never done a fiddle before.

Comment: A fiddle, hope this contains what you need.
http://jsfiddle.net/0g9z5mmw/

Comment: Do you want each <li> on a separate line?

Comment: Line? I want all three li:s to be in one horizontal row something like so. <li> <li> <li>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple solution is to remove `text-align: left` from `li` elements and use `display: table` to `ul`:

```css
.body-news {
}
.body-news ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
#newsbar li {
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-news">
    <ul id="newsbar">
        <li>
            <p>Widget1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Widget2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Widget3</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the float on the list items and change them to `inline-block`.

```
    #newsbar li{
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin: 15px 20px;
    }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0g9z5mmw/4/

Comment: Tried this, the li elements are now in a vertical column instead of a horizontal row. It is however desirable that each li has a "max-width: 300;

Comment: So, you are trying to create three columns that are each 300px wide and centered within the page?

Comment: Yes, with two modifications; the final width might be bit smaller/larger and it would be preferable with a max-width
Edit: these columns each hold a widget with text, news widgets with short excerpts. This is achieved with php and Wordpress.